# Jython zxJDBC.cursor fetchone() for a session variable ,I get an array

Tags: jython

I use Jython2.5.0, mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar, because my sever is Mysql5.0.38
There is a problem in my Jython application.

Two functions:

```
def act_query(query):  
    connection = conn    //conn is global and has been assigned when called  
    cursor = connection.cursor()  
    num_affected_rows = cursor.execute(query)  
    cursor.close()  
    connection.commit()  
    return num_affected_rows  

def get_row(query):  
    connection = conn  
    cursor = connection.cursor()  
    cursor.execute(query)  
    row = cursor.fetchone()  
    cursor.close()  
    return row
```

Then i do something like this:

```
query = """SELECT count(*) from test_db.test_table1 into @max"""  
act_query(query)  
get_query= """ select @max """  
row = get_row(get_query)  
print row
```

The output is something like: `array('b', [49, 52, 54, 50, 56, 48, 52])`

I try to find the reason and make a test like:

```
test_query = """select count(*) from test_db.test_table1"""  
row = get_row(test_query)  
print row
```

The output is the right answer

In fact this a script in CPython first with MySQLdb and I turn it into Jython with zxJDBC
It worked well in CPython but It can't work now.
In CPython the cursor can be defined as

cursor = connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)

but in zxJDBC there seem to be no choice for creating a cursor.
Is this the reason?
Please show me the way. Thanks!

Comment: I have got the answer.
zxJDBC get a session variable to be a byte array which can be convert to the right answer by str()

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer from jython mailist.
A session variable get by JDBC is of varbinary type. zxJDBC make it to be an array.The right output can be get by converting the array into int with str(byte[]).